# which GUI batch music converter has a similar UI to batch music converter/dBpoweramp?

Tags: software-recommendation, music, soundconverter

the nice thing with dBpoweramp is the UI has a tree-like structure which allows me to easily select multiple files/folders. I've looked at SoundCoverter and XCFA and their UI isn't as "easy" to use.

Any suggestions? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Personally I think that Soundconverter is far easier to use than dBpoweramp – especially for unskilled users – since you can just drag and drop objects from the file manager into it. Output path formatting is another thing but even that has reasonably simple-to-use presets.

Comment: @DavidFoerster while I do not mind drag-n-drop, selecting individual files from albums is not as intuitive compared to dBpoweramp. :)